# Characters set permutations with repetitions

Tags: javascript, combinatorics, underscore.js

The code bellow generates all the permutation(with repetitions) for given character set. Is there any better(simpler, more performant) way to do that?

```
var assert = require('chai').assert
var _ = require('underscore')

var multStr = function(left, rigth) {
  return _.chain(left).map(function(el) {
    return _(rigth).map(function(chr) {
      return el + chr
    })
  })
  .flatten()
  .value()
}

function solution(space, len) {
  return _.chain(
      _(len - 1).range()
    )
    .reduce(
      function(acc, next) {
          acc.push(
            multStr(
              _.last(
                acc
              ),
              space
            )
          )
          return acc
      },
      [space.split('')]
    )
    .flatten()
    .value()
}

assert.deepEqual(multStr(['ab'], 'ab'), ['aba', 'abb'])
assert.deepEqual(solution('abc', 1), ['a', 'b', 'c'])
assert.deepEqual(solution('a', 2), ['a', 'aa'])
assert.deepEqual(solution('ab', 2), ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb'])
assert.deepEqual(solution('abc', 3), [ 'a', 'b', 'c',
  'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc',
  'aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc',
  'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc',
  'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc'
])
```

Comment: Is the output of `solution('ab', 3)`? or `solution('abc', 3)` as expected? I'm not sure...

Comment: what do you mean?) I don't understand the question:)

Comment: If you run your code with `solution('abc', 3)`, do you get the result you expect? I would expect the following http://dpaste.com/2E3NZNZ, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: yep, you are right. There is a bug. I'll fix it and return to you

Comment: fixed. please check

Answer (score 2):

I think the code and the approach look good overall. I have just a few comments:

1) The indentation makes it a bit hard to read. A line like:

```
acc.push(multStr(_.last(acc), space))
```

Reads better than across many lines in my opinion.

2) You may consider using `concat` instead of `push`:

```
return acc.concat(multStr(_.last(acc), space))
```

You trade a bit of performance for it though as `concat` creates a new array.

3) The most notable problem I see with your code is that it is not very reusable. It only works for strings, while the idea and implementation certainly apply to arrays too. We can think of a string as an array of characters, so abstracting for arrays makes the code more reusable, since we can then do the string one trivially with `str.split('')`.

This leads to the name of the function `multStr`; it is too specific, and hungarian notation means you are probably over-specifying its functionality, it ought to be more abstract.

Intuitively you wrote code that is more abstract than it seems. I find the Haskell equivalent to your code quite elegant and concise, almost by accident:

```
[1..3] >>= \n -> replicateM n "ab"
```

The concept at hand is very general: lists are *monads*.

We can replicate this in JavaScript easily with lodash. We need `flatMap`, and `range`:

```
var {flatMap, range} = require('lodash')
```

Next we can loosely translate the Haskell implementations of `replicateM` and `sequence` to build `combinations`:

```
function combinations(n, xs) {
  return flatMap(range(1, n + 1), m => replicateM(m, xs))
}

function replicateM(n, x) {
  return sequence(Array(n).fill(x))
}

function sequence(ms) {
  return ms.reduce((ma, mb) => {
    return flatMap(ma, a => mb.map(b => a.concat(b)))
  }, [[]])
}
```

Now this is already more general, we pass an *array* of characters and get an array of arrays of characters that represent all the possible combinations of `n` length.

To make it work for your case you only need to split then join:

```
combinations(3, 'ab'.split('')).map(cs => cs.join(''))
/*^
[ 'a', 'b',
  'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb',
  'aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb',
  'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb'
]
*/
```

Comment: Nice answer! I'll try an return to you.

only one note. It's much better to use something meaningful like `acc`, `next` instead of `ma`, `mb`

Comment: @kharandziuk, I used `ma` as a convention for "monad of a" because `sequence` applies to any monad, I just narrowed it down for arrays here. But you are right, perhaps `acc` and `next` make more sense in this particular context.

Comment: do you know some nice explanation about monads?

Comment: This one looks good ["Functors, Applicatives, And Monads In Pictures"](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html)

Comment: read it, thanks . Actually I'm looking for something different. Instead of: "What is a monad?" i'm looking for "How to think in terms of monads?" or "How do I resolve problems in terms of monads?". Maybe some practical problems with solutions which give this knowledge. On the moment I can't imagine how should I think to create the `sequence` function from your answer

Comment: Generally to get some intuition whenever you see this structure `ma.flatMap(a => mb.map(b => f(a, b)))` you have something monadic. You can see in your `multStr` function `ma.map(a => mb.map(b => a + b)).flatten()` is basically the same pattern so it tells me that it is more general than it seems. Learning some Haskell would help in any case if you want to learn about it more in-depth.